# Missing styles when building app using Gtk.CssProvider

Tags: gtk, vala, cmake

I'm using cmake and following the instructions per Elementary OS site (https://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started#building-and-installing-with-cmake).

Everything looks good when compiling the app, but when building and installing the app the styles are missing. Perhaps I'm missing a step? Here's my code:

`var css_provider = new Gtk.CssProvider();
try {
    css_provider.load_from_path("style.css");
  } catch (GLib.Error e) {
    stderr.printf("%s", e.message);
  }
  Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(), css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find my own answer.

What I needed to do was install it in CMakeLists.txt

```
# install css
INSTALL(FILES src/style.css DESTINATION ${PKGDATADIR})
```

Then in the vala file I needed to call it where the destination would be:

```
try {
    css_provider.load_from_path(DESTINATION + "/style.css");
  } catch (GLib.Error e) {
    stderr.printf("%s", e.message);
  }
```

DESTINATION should be the location in the directory where you are saving the file. This can be done by assigning variables or hardcoding it.